# Best practice for including css and javascript files

Tags: javascript, css

I've always wondered about including javascript libraries and a mess of stylesheets in pages that don't ever use them. It got me wondering if maybe performance would improve, however slight, if I were to include these files on an as needed basis. Is there a best practice to go by on this? Some of these javascript libraries are very large and if they're not needed, it would seem to me that they shouldn't be included.

I'd like to hear the thoughts from others on this.

Comment: Clearly it is advantageous to not load anything you don't use. Best practice then may be to have a thorough knowledge of your site and what is required, then just don't load the rest. So what exactly are you looking for? A load on demand example or something?

Comment: Thanks, Kai. No, I'm not looking for a load on demand example. I've got a small library that I'm currently using for this but it's messy and I wanted to ask the question because I'd like to do away with it if the performance I'd be gaining by isn't that much

Comment: If proper caching and expires are used (e.g. use a CDN for common libraries) then a fair bit of the "network overhead" is eliminated. I'm not arguing for always loading/requiring the resource - but once it's loaded for a page on the site, the "cost" of loading it on others *may* be "unsubstantial enough" to not worry about. Now, *conflicts* caused by incorrect loading ..

Comment: @user2246674, right... caching! I didn't even think about this. Is there a library you'd recommend for this? Maybe something for PHP?

Comment: Also, if you are not using any asynchronous script loading then it's a good idea to put your script tags in footer so it doesn't hang the page load.

Comment: @NaN It's just about the headers and browser quirks. This mainly applies to statically served content, but even a PHP with *static/cacheable output* page can return the relevant cache control on a GET or whatnot.

Comment: @SheikhHeera, that's very good advice. Thanks, I'll do that from now on.

Comment: Brian below offered up `require.js`. Does anyone here any any comments on that library? I think I like the caching idea best though

Comment: "Best" infers a comparison to something, so what are your criteria for "best"? Fastest to load? Least stress on the server? Ease of maintenance? …

Comment: `require.js` and caching achieve different goals.  It all depends on what you are trying to achieve.  If you load cached javascript but don't use it, you have still spent the time and memory to process the code.  AMD allows you to manage dependencies and only load what you need... and you can still use caching.

Comment: Caching is my favorite option here because it speeds up the page load times.

Comment: @BrianGenisio, yeah, Brian, I'd say speed would be my main consideration.

Comment: Can anyone recommend a caching libaray for PHP?

Comment: Regardless of what you decide, please consider that I answered your question pretty directly.  AMD is the best practice for including files on an "as needed basis".  It isn't necessarily the answer to the fastest (though it might still be).

Comment: Absolutely, Brian. I intended to accept.

Comment: I'll go ahead and try Brian's library and see how things improve. I really appreciate everyone's input on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are talking about [Asynchronous Module Definitions](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/AsynchronousDefinition) (AMD).

One of the more popular implementations of this is [Require.js](http://requirejs.org/).  Check it out.

Comment: Thank you Brian, heading there now

Comment: RequireJS can't load CSS, can it?

Comment: Not explicitly (http://requirejs.org/docs/faq-advanced.html#css) but here is a plugin: https://github.com/guybedford/require-css

Comment: I would not load (primary) CSS dynamically - doing so creates more chance for FOUC.

Comment: Good point, @user2246674.  You'd have to be careful to not display any content that uses the dynamic CSS until you get the callback that tells you the CSS is loaded.  That could get tricky.